# How do I select everything before Picture_1.png with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to select with JS everything before `Picture_1.png` in this url:

```
"http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/development/system/photos/215/cropped_thumb/Picture_1.png"
```

so that the end result is this :

```
"http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/development/system/photos/215/cropped_thumb"
```

Comment: If you want to do this with vanilla js, why did you tag it with jQuery?

Comment: @alec, how do you implement regex in js?

Comment: Example: `var match = "http://.../cropped_thumb/Picture_1.png".match(/(.+)\/Picture_1.png/)[1];`, but Ender's solution is a lot cleaner :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/development/system/photos/215/cropped_thumb/Picture_1.png";
var trimmed = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gAxPx/

Comment: Remember to choose this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly called getting the "dirname".  A good starting point is

http://phpjs.org/functions/dirname:388

There are likely other versions if you Google for "javascript dirname"

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with regular expressions.

```
var text = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/development/system/photos/215/cropped_thumb/Picture_1.png";
var dirname = text.match(/(.+)\//)[1];
```